# Don't understand principle of "invited to chat"

Tags: support, chat

I have no experience with "chat", but today I got an "invitation", then I entered the chat-room: three members, two of them do not know what they should do there/why they were "invited" ("Why is $\beta$ in $Q$") - and me: the third (except of the owner). Looking at the user "Mary Star" I found she has about 80 Chat-rooms, many of the same name and also three of the chat-title where I was now invited.
Is there something how one can help the user to manage the chatting properly? Or is this (look at the user's site for chatrooms) really the intended behave? (And finally: there was not even an input-line for me in that "chat")

see the user's chat-list    http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/119089/mary-star
See the chat-room: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/32572

Comment: The fact that there was no input line is because you are linked to the transcript, not the room itself. In the right there is a button to join the room. (Or for some reason you are not logged in to chat.)

Comment: Thanks @quid; did not know this technique at all... (I'm not a good "chatter" also in RL)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a feature that allows users to invite any other user that has a chat account to a chat room. But this is really not meant for just inviting random users you don't know, but only for cases where you have a reasonable expectation that the user actually wants to be invited.

This is a misuse of that feature, and I expect that the user will be warned by a moderator about this.

Comment: It is not completely random in this case. But the user in question might use the feature too generously.

Comment: @quid I mean random in terms of inviting users you have no previous connection with. Or is there anything non-random here that I missed?

Comment: The user in question invited me sometimes to point me to their questions. The motivation being, or so I assumed, that I already had answered some of their questions. This is unusual and maybe an overuse of the feature. However, it did not bother me personally as it was not too frequent and the user was nice about it, and took a simple "sorry can't help on this" as satisfactory response. The linked room seems to serve that purpose too.